# Sort Output of Loop and Display

Tags: bash

I have a script that loops through a directory and for each file counts the iterations of a certain word. When the script is run the number of iterations is output to the screen for each file. I however would like to first sort the list before it's output.

I know I need to output to sort somewhere, but I'm not sure how to implement this. In a non scripting language I would probably put the output of the loop into an array, but I don't think that's what's meant to be done with Bash.

```
for f in /home/reviews_folder/*
do
    tr -s ' ' '\n' < $f | grep - c '<Author>'
done
```

I don't think I would put the sort in the loop, so how would i create a pipeline between the loop and the sort?

Comment: `cat /home/reviews_folder/* | tr -s ' ' '\n' | grep - c '<Author>' | sort`?

Comment: Your current code doesn't appear to output filenames, just the counts. Also `- c`' looks like a typo

Comment: @Biffen You don't need the parentheses; a `for` loop is a command by itself.

Comment: Yeah I hadn't put in the code to output the filenames, but honestly I've been trying for a couple hours and can't figure out how. I was think it's something like | sort & & echo basename $FilePath but am not sure how to arrange it

Answer (score 5):

A loop is a compound command, and each command in the body of the loop inherits its standard output from the loop. That means you can simply pipe the loop itself to `sort`.

```
for f in /home/reviews_folder/*; do
  tr -s ' ' '\n' < "$f" | grep -c '<Author>'
done | sort
```